# OpenCV Error in Android: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate)

Tags: android, opencv, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am using opencv in Android Studio to increase the red color proportion in an image. But when I run the function after about 30 times, the program crashes and shows the error.

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory(Failed to allocate *****bytes)
```

I have searched many relating questions and many people say add **Mat.release()** could solve this problem. I added the Mat.release in my function but it does not help. The program still crashes after I run it over 30 times.

Here is my Code. Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

```
public void addRedColor(int red){

Mat img = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(src, img);

List<Mat> bitplane = new ArrayList<>(img.channels());
Core.split(img, bitplanes);
Mat redChannel = new Mat();
Core.add(bitplane.get(0), new Scalar(red), redChannel);
bitplane.set(0, redChannel);
Core.merge(bitplane, img);

// release the Mat
img.release();
bitplane.get(0).release();
bitplane.get(1).release();
bitplane.get(2).release();
redChannel.release();

}
```

Comment: Every single `new` call should have corresponding call of `delete`. Note that `release` is a different thing and only frees some internal fields of Mat

Comment: @DmitriiZ. it's Java, not C++

Comment: I am also a newbie in java and android, I tried to **delete**  the Mat in java. But it seems that there is no delete function for OpenCV in java.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to waste memory with new Mat and force the garbage collector before the end of the method

```
    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();
```